# Where i can find the data submitted if i leave the form's with no action attribute?

Tags: php, database, forms, attributes, action

I launched my website with data submission form but forgot to put action attribute into my form code. I really need help to know where i can find the place of the data submitted if the case is like that. Thank you.

```
<form id="WebToLeadForm" method="POST" name="WebToLeadForm">
```

Comment: *where i can find the place of the data submitted if the case is like that.* it will submit to itself. you can check on MDN for [`<form>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target).

Answer (score 0):

> I really need help to know where i can find the place of the data submitted

The "default action" for a `<form>` when none is specified is to use the current document's address.  So it's posting to the current URL at the time the form is loaded.  Of course, you can observe this using your browser's debugging tools.

> forgot to put action attribute into my form code

That sounds like a simple enough fix.  If you need to specify an `action` attribute then update your code to specify it.  Not much need for panic, just correct the bug.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i still can't find the data. Maybe you can describe the steps or something more spesific where is the data placed

Comment: @SuryaNugraha: What do you mean by "find the data"?  Once the form is posted to the server, do you *do anything* with the information that was posted?  If your code ignores that data then there's nowhere to "find" it, you're ignoring it.  If the code stores that data somewhere then that's likely where you should look.  Nobody here knows anything about your code aside from the one line shown in the question.